Convert .bib to .docx in command line (as does: https://www.bibtex.com/c/bibtex-to-ama-converter/)
I frequently use the excellent following website to convert my bibliography from .bib to .docx for coauthors working with me on scientific stuff who don't use latex:
https://www.bibtex.com/c/bibtex-to-ama-converter/
More precisely, the output of the website is a table with 2 columns: the first one is the numbering of appearance of the references in the .bib file and the second one is filled with the references in the AMA (American Medical Association) format. AMA was taken as an example, an can be replaced by any other format.
Is there a command line equivalent?
The content of the .bib can be something like that:
% content of ref.bib



@article{TheAuthorOne2023,
  title = {The title1},
  volume = {62},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/11.1111},
  number = {10},
  journal = {The journal1},
  publisher = {Publisher1},
  author = {author one and author two},
  year = {2022},
  month = oct,
}


@article{TheAuthorTwo2023,
  title = {The title2},
  volume = {62},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/11.1112},
  number = {10},
  journal = {The journal2},
  publisher = {Publisher2},
  author = {author one and author two},
  year = {2022},
  month = oct,
}



Here is the screen shot of the content of the word document generated on by the website:


could you explain a bit more? a .bib is a database, whereas .docx is (I think) a formatted document. so it isn't clear how you'd 'convert' the former into the latter. something has to provide information about which entries to include and how to format them. so you'd normally convert a .tex file, as far as I know. you could convert a .bib to another database format e.g. a format used by some tool used by word users.

Many thanks for your comment @cfr. you are right: .bib is a database, but in the website you can just copy/paste your bib file and it outputs you a table with the reference in order of appearance of your bib formated in AMA (American Medical Association). I edited the question accordingly. Please do not hesitate to ask for other details if needed

it seems a bit specific for there to be a command line tool just for this. having said that, I'm not a medic, so I doubt I'd know if somebody had made one. but you could always write a script wrapper around some more general tool if you need to do it frequently.

thank you for your comment @cfr. The point here is not specifically to convert to AMA but having a command (or a series of them) to convert a .bib file into a word document. AMA format was taken as an example but could be replaced by another one

Would just a simple latex document with \nocite{*} and a bibliography do? The either copy&paste from the resulting pdf to word or use pandoc from the command line to convert to word?

what @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz said. or use biber to convert to some database format word understands.
